# How to insert based on where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that inserts data into one database (database1), based on results from another (database2).  My concern is, when I run this query that i'll be introducing some potential duplicates.

My query that works fine:

```
Insert into Customers (CustomerID, dateCreated)(
Select CustomerID, datecreated
FROM         Database2.dbo.Customers
Where datecreated between @startdate and @enddate))
```

Now, i'd like to catch the duplicates by checking the CustomerID field, and not inserting into database1 if it already exists inside database1.

I thought something like this:

```
Insert into Customers (CustomerID, dateCreated)(
    Select CustomerID, datecreated
    FROM         Database2.dbo.Customers
    Where datecreated between @startdate and @enddate))
Where not exists (Select customerid from customers)
```

I know that's not quite right, but i'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a left join.
Checking that the joined table customerid value is null insures that it doesn't exist in the source database.

```
INSERT into Database1.dbo.Customers 
    (CustomerID,
     dateCreated)
SELECT 
     CustomerID, 
     datecreated
FROM Database2.dbo.Customers c2
LEFT JOIN Database1.dbo.Customers c1 ON c1.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID
WHERE c2.datecreated between @startdate and @enddate
  AND c1.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if not exists and it will simply scan the table and see if it exists or not. Note, it will not read the data making it an efficient way to check.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 from Database1.dbo.customers WHERE customerid = 'the id you want to not duplicate')
BEGIN
Insert into Customers (CustomerID, dateCreated)(
Select CustomerID, datecreated
FROM         Database.dbo.Customers
Where datecreated between @startdate and @enddate))
END
```

Comment: This only works for one row at a time.  Michael G's solution will work for set-based inserts.